# Push ViewController to Scene is not calling Init method each time in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

hello friend i want to push view controller to scene in cocos2d. i success push to scene.but when second time i push to scene at that time i can't update the scene by web services.i want to update all data when i enter in it.i try Google but not get anything.please help me.

push to scene by following code..

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:[CCDirector sharedDirector]
                                               animated: YES];
```

i  have all value in int method of HelloWord and i want to call all time that method.but push second time it not call so that all old values are there

also Can i push particular scene.

Comment: CCDirector is a singleton, so it's created only once, which means the init method will only be called once.

Comment: ok it call once but how to update all value when call helloword scene

Answer (score 0):

You should try this -

Make a new method for refreshing UI. Declare it in header like this-

```
-(void)refreshUIWithData:(id)dataSource;
```

In the implementation, define it's body by transferring all the code from init in this method-

```
-(void)refreshUIWithData:(id)dataSource
{
//refresh code here
}
```

Then, from the init call it like this -

```
-(id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        [self refreshUIWithData:nil];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Later when you have got the data from web services, 
call again the same method with fresh dataSource instance.